# How to setup seller subdomain page for vendors?

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-vendor, multidomain, sellers-dashboard

I want to setup a **different page** for **sellers** using the subdomain "seller.websitename.com" where they can have their own dashboard and every options required to them. 
Please help me setting this?

Answer (score 0):

Standard Magento is not prepared for creating such a platform. You can easily setup different frontends for each seller by creating separate website/store views for them but the admin panel is always the same. That being said there are modules for magento that offers such functionality, you can search them here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=7&pl=1:403&eb=0&hp=0&q=marketplace&t=0&p=1